# flex for ARM compilation -?

Tags: apache-flex

i am trying to find out how to build my .as for mobile browser on Android 2.2 smartphone.
I downloaded latest distribution of "Hero" SDK, but all tutorials show only how to create mobile project with Flash Builder. Any idea how to build .swf from command line mxmlc for mobile ? 
Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this page:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/faq.html

Can I build mobile applications using only Flex SDK "Hero" without Flash Builder "Burrito"?
Yes. However, in order to get your application onto a device for testing, you will need to install the Android SDK, and use a combination of the Adobe AIR SDK command-line packaging tool and the Android SDK's "adb" tool.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffb.html

Haven't done this myself but that looks right.

Good luck,

Shaun

Comment: Thanks, but why do you mention AIR? I need my script to run on browser, AIR is alternative to browser. I am missing something?

Comment: Never mind, i read http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/faq.html#differences. Looks like with present SDK i can only build standalone flex app for AIR. Does it mean i can use VideoObject in such application?

Comment: @user270398 I imagine anything that is available in AIR will be available but I don't know of that particular class, sorry like I said haven't really dove into this yet aside from getting the example code running.  I imagine AIR is used since it's closer to Java in terms of disk access and things of that sort.  (not in any way to undermine your knowledge) Flex is AS3 plus flex libraries, AIR is Flex plus libraries, so you shouldn't be losing anything here really (except the ability to compile as a web app as well), I mentioned AIR only with regard to what the documentation says you need to do.